# identityserver4 with oidc-client implicit flow redirect not showing login page

Tags: javascript, identityserver4

I am trying to use the oidc-client with identityserver4 using the implicit flow.
Here is my Client Configuration.

```
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "crushingtheweb.ui",
     ClientName = "Crushing The Web.UI",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
     RequireConsent = false,
     AllowedCorsOrigins = new[] { "http://localhost:52668" },
     AllowedScopes = new List<string>
     {
         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
         "ctw"
      },
      RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:52668/callback"},
      PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {                                                                                                                           "http://localhost:52668/out" }                                 
 }
```

Here is the oidc-client, client configuration and my call to signinRedirect.

```js
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(UserManager)
export class AdminChat {

    userManager: UserManager;

    constructor(userManager) {

        this.userManager = userManager;
        console.log('oidc', this.userManager);

        let config = {
            authority: 'http://localhost:65027',
            client_id: "crushingtheweb.ui",
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost:52668/callback",
            response_type: "id_token token",
            scope: "openid profile ctw",
            post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:52668/out",
        };

        var mgr = new UserManager(config);
        mgr.signinRedirect();
            

    }// ctor()

}// AdminChat class
```

The login page is never shown and it immediately redirects to the callback url, so obviously the user is still undefined.
Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any logs from Identity Server?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question. One possibility is that you *are* already logged in to the Identity Server application, which would explain the immediate redirect. You've suggested this isn't the case, so it'll be worth looking through your Identity Server logs as suggested by @m3n7alsnak3.

Comment: I attempted to answer this one that id_token wasn't supported by Implicit, but someone responded that it is.  They are waiting for more information, not sure what.  Can you post a github repo?

Comment: @JakeJ It was me. I've commented here (above yours). A repo is a good idea, yes.

Comment: OK, when I was having issues with IdentityServer like this, I put breakpoints on the server side in the AccountController login() method then stepped through it.  See if it's reaching that.